# jquery plugin for selectboxes

Tags: jquery, plugins, drop-down-menu

As you know, there are many jquery plugins for selectboxes, which make the selectboxes / dropdown menu more beautiful.

I'm looking for one, which can update the options of the others selectboxes instantly.

The reason is, i write a football manager game, and this is now the lineup section

Here a link to an screenshot: [image]

So, with the classic style of the dropdown menus, if i take a player, then this player will be disabled in the other select-elements, so there is no problem.

But when I want to use jQuery plugin to make the menu more beautiful, the options aren't disabled any more, if I pick one player.

I've tried *ddSlick* and [this one](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown), but the options on the other selects aren't disabled anymore, if I pick one player.

So i'm asking now for a beautiful plugin, which can disabled other options instantly.

here is my code for deactivating the other selections, if you want:

```
var player1 = select = document.getElementById( 'player1' );
var player2 = select = document.getElementById( 'player2' );
// More...

var string1 = null;
var string2 = null;
// More...

function preventDupes( select) {
    var options = select.options,
        len = options.length;
    while( len-- ) {
        if ((options[len].value == string1 ||
             options[len].value == string2 ||
             /*More...*/ )){

                options[ len ].disabled = true;
        }
        else{
            options[ len ].disabled = false;
        }

    }
    //select.options[ index ].disabled = true;
}

player1.onchange = function() {

    string1 = player1.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    preventDupes.call(this, player2);
    // more player...
};
```

The functions for player2 to player10 are still the same pattern like `player1.onchange()`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple jsFiddle which does what you need and should work with many players. The loop within a loop would eventually degrade and I know there's a better way to do this, but it's late and this works...

To appease the SO gods, you should use an array rather than separate variables

```
   var players = ["player1", "player2", "player3", "player4", "player5"];
```

[See my example here](http://jsfiddle.net/rnsgkfz9/)

Comment: My options of the selects are filled from a mysql table, because each user of my site has his own unique players, so how can I fill the names in this array?